# $.getScript not working within a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why the $getScript doesn't work within the click function on firefox browser but does work on other browsers. The same code outside the click function works on firefox. Can someone explain what the problem is?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var page = "";
    page = window.location.href;
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
             $( "#socialemail" ).click(function() {
                $.getScript('/social-media.php?email&' + page);
                window.location.href="mailto:?subject=text here Systems&body="+escape(window.location.href);
             });  
       });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `$.getScript()` is asynchronous and I expect you want to wait for the results of it, you should execute the following `window.location.href` property change in a callback function passed to `$.getScript()`. Something like

```
var page = "";
page = window.location.href;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         $( "#socialemail" ).click(function(e) {
            // prevent the default action of clicking on whatever element
            // with id 'socialemail' is
            e.preventDefault();

            $.getScript('/social-media.php?email&' + page, function () { 
                // run this after the script has been fetched
                window.location.href="mailto:?subject=text here Systems&body="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
            });
         });  
   });
```

Comment: I changed to your suggestion and the php file is now updated (thanks!) however the mailto window doesn't appear in any of the browsers.

Comment: Where is the `mailto` attempting to go? There is no address in the string that starts with `mailto:...`

Comment: I'm trying to create an email to friend icon and when clicked - gets the current url, updates a php file, and then opens the users email and inputs the subject line and the url of the webpage.  The mailto is left blank intentionally.